# FHIR and DocumentReference

Tags: hl7-fhir

How can I get `DocumentReference` for particular document from `DocumentManifest` list of documents?

Here is an example of returned `DocumentManifest`

```
  {
     "title": {
     },
     "id": {
     },
     "updated": {
     },
     "content": {
        "type": {
           "@id": "urn:uuid:xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx",
           "text": "Patient Document List"
        },
        "resourceType": "DocumentManifest",
        "text": {
           "status": "generated",
           "div": "<div xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">Some Test ORG</div>"
        },
        "contained": {
           "resourceType": "Patient",
           "identifier": {
              "use": "official",
              "system": "",
              "value": "12345678987654321"
           }
        },
        "subject": {
           "reference": "Patient Documents"
        },
        "recipient": {
           "organization": {
              "display": "Some Test ORG"
           }
        },
        "created": "2018-02-09T13:26:53-07:00",
        "status": "current",
        "content": {
           "reference": [
              "Binary/DOCUMENT-1000123",
              "Binary/DOCUMENT-1000124",
              "Binary/DOCUMENT-1000125"
           ]
        }
     }
  }
```

I have tried to use something like

`GET [service-url]/DocumentReference/?_query=generate&uri=[service-url]/BINARY/DOCUMENT-1000125`

but I had no luck.

Comment: Why do you think that there are DocumentReferences available? This has just referenced some binaries directly, so that's what you'd retrieve...?

Comment: @GrahameGrieve Based on a documentation: `A document manifest gathers a set of DocumentReference resources into a single package that may be the subject of workflow such as access control, auditing, and targeted delivery.`http://hl7.org/fhir/DSTU2/documentmanifest.html

Answer (score 0):

That DocumentManifest is not pointing at a DocumentReference. It is point at a document. 
FYI: What you have shown is not compliant with IHE-MHD use of DocumentReference/DocumentManifest/Binary.

Comment: But documentation states `A document manifest gathers a set of DocumentReference resources into a single package that may be the subject of workflow such as access control, auditing, and targeted delivery.`http://hl7.org/fhir/DSTU2/documentmanifest.html Above example it is what I have got from provided API